# Change Account Owner Field to related opportunity owner

Tags: process-builder, sales-cloud, process

I would like to change the account owner field when an opportunity is Closed Won by a different owner. Example if Jane close wins as opportunity under John's account, the account owner field should automatically change to Jane.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please see [ask] for what we look for.

Answer (score 1):

So you want change account owner whenever opportunity closed right?
Here is the steps:

1. Create process builder in opportunity (run when record changes)
2. Add criteria (in this case stage equals closed won)
3. Add action **Update records**, in record type choose 2nd option and lookup to account
4. Set value for your new account owner
5. Activate process builder and test it

Comment: Thanks for this. I am able to setup this process till step 4. What value would you advise here?

Comment: Set value of your account owner to be opportunity owner id. Have you found that?